# Using cursor to put contacts into a list view does not work when moving down to APK 22 in android studio

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, arraylist

I have created this function that uses a cursor to get all the contacts stored into an arraylist which is then displayed using a listview in a fragment. It works fine when I test it with a tablet running APK 23, but when I move down to APK 22 it doesn't work. What is the reasoning behind this?

Here is the function:

```
// grabs the contacts and stores them into the arraylist
public void GetContactsIntoArrayList() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Function was hit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        contacts.add(name);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name + " added to the array list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: It's not actually putting the contacts into the array list. I know it hits the function, as the toast saying the function was invoked displays on the screen. It's really confusing, as like I said, it works when the tablet is running APK 23. It's just when we revert to the prior APK it doesn't.